# ALTER Query Not Working

Tags: mysql, database, primary-key, unique-constraint, alter

I have two tables: `cleanup` and `uniqueEntries`. They both have an auto-increment `id` as primary key. The table structure of `uniqueEntries` comes from `cleanup` as such:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE uniqueEntries LIKE cleanup"; //create table to store all unique entries
doQuery($sql, "success creating uniqueEntries", "failed creating uniqueEntries"); //perform query
```

Table `cleanup` contains duplicate usernames. As I am moving data into `uniqueEntries`, I want to make sure I am not inserting any duplicates. So I need to implement an `ALTER` statement on `User_ID`. I did that as such:

```
$sql = "ALTER IGNORE TABLE uniqueEntries ADD UNIQUE (User_ID)"; //make User_ID unique
doQuery($sql, "success adding constraint to uniqueEntries", "failed adding constraint to uniqueEntries"); //perform query
```

However, unlike all of my other queries the `ALTER` query does not get processed. I get `failed adding constraint to uniqueEntries`. What am I doing wrong?

Below is my doQuery function:

```
function doQuery($sql, $success, $fail){
    global $conn;
        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        eLog( $success ); //log outcome
    } else {
        eLog( $fail ); //log outcome
    } 
}
```

Comment: don't log a fixed (and useless) error message. have the db TELL you what went wrong: `eLog($fail . $conn->error)` or whatever your DB interface lib's error message source is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed @Marc B's advice to output the message from `$conn()->error` and learned that `TEXT` column type does not allow `ALTER` operations.

```
BLOB/TEXT column 'User_ID' used in key specification without a key length
```

So, I went back to my table query and switched the `User_ID` column from `TEXT` to `VARCHAR(15)` and I was able to run the `ALTER` query without problems.